# AG-Grid column drop panel custom message

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

[image]

I have been playing around with [AG-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com) and vue. I am looking to replace the default message  in the Column drop panel  for grouping (circled in the screenshot).
I have looked through the documentation but I did not find a way to overwrite it (not sure if i have missed reading some).

Am thinking of using the document selector to override the text but thought of checking with the community here to see if there's a cleaner approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `localeText` to achieve this.

Use `rowGroupColumnsEmptyMessage` key for `localeText`.

Reference: [Using localeText](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-internationalisation/)

```
<ag-grid-angular
  ...
  [localeText]="localeText"
></ag-grid-angular>
```